# Setting UserDefault in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm learning Swift 3 and trying to get to grips with `UserDefaults`. This is the code:

```
    UserDefaults.standard.set("asher", forKey: "name")

    let name = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "name")

    print(name)
```

When I run it I get a breakpoint at line 2 and when I comment out line 2 I get a breakpoint at line 1.

Apart from the normal things in the console I get:

```
(lldb)
```

Can anyone please explain my mistake?

Comment: I get the output `Optional(asher)`, as one would expect. Perhaps you accidentally set a breakpoint in your code?